# How to download apk file of telegram app on android?

Tags: applications, apk, downloading, telegram

Telegram allow to install app only on Google Play Store but I  want to download apk file and send to my friend because his Android device which does not have access to Google Play Store. Is it possible to download apk file of Telegram app on android without any apk website downloader only from right apps or right ways?

Thank in advance for all of you Stackexchange Community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the app [APK Extractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui&hl=en_US) to get the APK of the application you want on your device to send, or you can find a version of the app on a mirror site, like [APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/).

I have used both in the past and have not had problems with them.

There are other apps similar to APK Extractor that allows you to obtain the APK, like [Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup). I have not used this one personally, but people have recommended it before.

Answer (score 0):

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

[Yalp Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) has the option to select the download directory to store the downloaded APKs. Yalp Store fetches apps from Play Store.